# Jira - Sharing filters with many users in one go

Tags: filter, jira

I created about a dozen filters. Currently they are private, but I want to share them with my many colleagues.

I saw the Share button on the filter page (top right). But that only allows you to share the filter with 1 user at the time.

I am an administrator. How can I share my filters with everybody in for example a user group?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to share the filter to users in group
 1. Save your filter by click on Save as button next to filter name by providing appropriate filter name
 2. Filter once saved will appear under Favorite filters section in screens left panel and details link appear next to your saved filter name
 3. Click on Details >> Edit permissions
 4. now you will see Add Viewers and Add Editors where you can select group, project, any logged in user or public in drop down. 
 5. Select appropriate category and group and click on add